# Ubuntu 17.10 weird system freeze, no errors in syslog

Tags: freeze, 17.10, nodejs, wayland, atom

I've encountered an issue that I have no idea how to debug properly.

Recently the system started randomly freezing; the cursor, and also the keys including numLock, often requiring a hard reset.

However, after rebooting, when I check the syslog, it appears as if everything went as usual, in fact, the system didn't even freeze, and I can see logs from after the freeze.

I've noticed this happening while using the Atom editor, and also a nodemon NodeJS script running next to it, but I don't do anything else really, so I can't be sure that these cause it, and even if they do, I still have no idea how to debug them.

I'm using 17.10 wayland on a lenovo ideapad 700, and with a custom 4.14.0-rc3+ kernel, due to a bug that hasn't been fixed in the mainline kernel yet.

Any ideas on where should I get clues from?

**update:**

```
Nov  4 20:08:03 feckaLaptop gnome-session-binary[1028]: Entering running state
```

Apparently gnome "got out of running state", but it isn't logged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the plugins in Atom was broken, which somehow caused a system-wide UI freeze. Reinstalling the plugins seems to have fixed the problem.

Comment: which atom plugin?

Comment: I don't know for certain, I didn't go through all of them. However it isn't entirely atom related. I haven't used atom for months now, and I still get occasional freezes, a lot less often though.

Comment: If that's the case can you de-accept your answer?